# Custom form_for to validation record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I am trying to create a custom `form_for` where I check if the record exists in the table or not. I've done tons of research but haven't come up with anything useful.

My current approach is to create a simple search form and display all similar records. However, that's not what I am looking for. Ideal scenario would be:

1. Get record's name from `form_for`
2. Check if this record present
3. If present - redirect to one page. If not - redirect to another page

My controller:

```
def validate_name
  @room = Room.new
  name = params[:name]

  if name != nil
    puts "Redirect to page A"
  else
    puts "Redirect to page B"
  end
end
```

The problem here is that whenever the user comes to the page it automatically triggers the code above. My goal is to create a form validation that tries to find the exact record and then redirect based on `if else` condition.

Current `form_for`:

```
= form_for(Room.new, url: name_room_path, method: :get, action: :validate_name) do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.submit
```

I am sure that my form is incorrect too because I got lost. I found ways to create custom forms but can't figure out how to trigger database check based on the user's input.

PS: these are not `new` or `update` actions.

Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class RoomsController < ActionController::Base
  def validate_name
    if params[:name] && Room.where(name: params[:name]).last.present?
      puts "Redirect to page A"
    elsif params[:name] && Room.where(name: params[:name]).last.nil?
      puts "Redirect to page B"
    end
  end
end
```

in routes.rb:

```
get '/rooms/validate_name', to: 'rooms#validate_name'
```

in view:

```
<%= form_tag(rooms_validate_name_path, :method => :get  )do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :name %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could use `find_by(name: ...)`. Would not need to use the .last or present check. It will return nil if not found.